# Using modern threads safely in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, executorservice

I am really trying to learn the newer "modern" java(10+, preferably 12), and I would appreciate your assistance with implementing threads in a safe and accurate manner.

So assume I have this simple class:

```
    Public class dosomething{
    private int x=0;
    private int y=0;
    public dosomething(int x, int y){
    this.y=y;
    this.x=x;
    }
    public dosomething getter(){return(new dosomething(x,y)}
    public void addition(int h, int i){
    x = x + h;
    y = y + i;
    }
}
```

So I am trying to create two threads that get by reference an object of dosomething(given class):

First thread will create 5 pairs of random numbers and will utilize the addition function(one after the other).

Second thread will use the getter function to request 5 times to see the values of the objects(using some kind of idling of course).

The threads should run in parallel and the results obtained by the second thread should be the results of using the first thread accordingly.

**What I am currently looking for:** is how to do it so both threads are synchronized. I thought of doing that in the dosomething class, so I could securely and hopefuly efficiently implement "*multiple readers single writer*"

So for the first(regarding creation of the two threads): Using SecureRandom, this is what i came up with:

First Thread:

```
dosomething do;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                int h = rand.nextInt(200);
                int j = rand.nextInt(200);
                do.addition(h, j);
                System.out.println("x="+do.x+"y="+do.y);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("\n Error occured: Thread interrupted");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

(Note: both Threads have constructors that use super(), but i omitted them in writing to make it shorter)

Thread2:

```
    dosomething do;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("result: "+do.getter());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("\n Error occured: Thread interrupted");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation in Main is simpler using Executors.newCachedThreadPool.

What I am trying to Learn/do is how to implement multiple readers single writer, and if possible, using modern java. if someone could show me the modern way of doing that, it would really help me a lot.

Edit: A friendly user here commented that dealing with each thread individually is not considered modern, so if possible, I would very much appreciate if you could show me the right way to write them in a Modern way.

Thank you very much for helping me learn!

EDIT2: My attempt on dosomething class using reentrant lock:

```
Public class dosomething{
    private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);
    private int x=0;
    private int y=0;
    public dosomething(int x, int y){
    lock.writeLock().lock();
        try{
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }finally{
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
    public dosomething getter(){return(new dosomething(x,y)}
    public void addition(int h, int i){
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try{
    x = x + h;
    y = y + i;
    return //I don't know how to return x and y correctly here
    }
    finally{
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Though I am not sure how to return both x and y here...

Comment: Unrelated: in java class names go UpperCamelCase. Beyond that, I find your question too broad. You should ask *one* specific question ... after doing your initial research. And note: any code that directly deals with "raw" threads isn't considered "modern" at all. When you write "multi threaded" code in 2019, for java 10 and newer ... ideally, your code doesn't say thread anyway. Instead you submit tasks into an ExecutorService, and you use (Completeable)Futures for example. And these topics are heavily documented ... thus: prior research!

Comment: Okay i will soon be editing the post to reflect my problem. Basically: the problem is about synchronization in dosomething class, how to synchronize the threads so there will be Multiple Readers one Writer.

Regarding the UpperCamelCase, will use it from now, thank you!